# How to add a line break inside a bash string?

Tags: bash, quoting, special-characters

I have the following bash string and I need to add a line break to it, before the 'Hello' string:

```
bash -c "echo 'Hello' > /location/file"
```

I already tried adding it with different variations of the `\n` syntax; Before the double quotes, inside the range of the double quotes, and with different variations of escaping.

How could I add a line break just before the 'Hello' string, so to make it appear in the second row?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are (at least) three options here.

1. Use a literal newline:

```
bash -c "echo '
Hello' > /location/file"
```

2. Use `printf` (or the non-standard `echo -e`), which expands backslash escaped characters as part of the commands themselves (of which both are shell builtins):

```
bash -c "printf '\n%s\n' Hello > /location/file"
```

3. Use bash's nonstandard `$'` quoting, which expands backslash escaped characters as part of the shell:

```
bash -c "echo $'\nHello' > /location/file
```

Comment: There are three options, and the third one (which I am amazed to see not mentioned in any answer here since it is an exceedingly common answer to the problem of `echo` and backslash, given several times over on this very WWW site alone) _is_ standard.

Comment: @JdeBP: What would that 3rd method be? `printf`, literal newlines within a quoted string?

Answer (score 7):

You may use `$'\n'`:

```
$ bash -c "echo $'\nHello'" >somefile
```

The Bash manual mentions this:

> Words of the form `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word expands to
> string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the
> ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape sequences, if present, are decoded
> as follows:

(table of standard escape sequences left out)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with:

```
bash -c "echo $'\nHello'"
```